# Android music player application not opening

Tags: android

I am trying to make a simple application of a music player with simple `ImageButton`s for play and pause.

I tried doing it but from the emulator, at run-time, an error appears "unfortunately not able to open the appication."

I tried with only the code for play button and it worked but when the code for pause button is added the run-time error occurs. Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

Thank you.

```
public class Audio1Activity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "AudioDemo";
    private static final String isPlaying = "Media is Playing"; 
    private static final String notPlaying = "Media has stopped Playing"; 
    private MediaPlayer player;
    ImageButton playbtn,pausebtn;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        player= MediaPlayer.create(this , R.raw.a1);
        playbtn=(ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.image_button1);

        player.setLooping(false); 

        playbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){


        public void onClick(View v) {
            demoPlay();

        }
    });

    pausebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            demoPause();
        }
    });  

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        player.pause();
    }

    private void demoPause(){
        player.pause();
        Toast.makeText(this, notPlaying, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, notPlaying);
    }

    private void demoPlay(){
        player.start();
        Toast.makeText(this, isPlaying, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, isPlaying);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is you are not setting the `pausebtn` to be of the `ImageButton` widget.

Something like this should do it:

```
pausebtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.name_of_image_button_in_your_layout_xml);

if (pausebtn != null){
    pausebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            demoPause();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: ohh yes i dnt do that. thanx for the help

Comment: Then mark this answer as correct and click on the checkmark beside the answer to let others know that it has been resolved :)

Comment: can u tell me how to add a list of music files present in my raw folder to my application.

Answer (score 0):

```
player.prepare();
```

try put this line before player.start();

Comment: it still says application has stopped